# why ruby code crash/exit after my second exec call?

Tags: ruby, system-calls

```
puts "start"
ret1 = exec('pwd')
puts ret1
ret2= exec('hostname')
puts ret2

a = "."
puts a

exec('ls ~')
////code exit from here... not any other output why?
puts a
puts a
puts a
```

My this code exit after second call of exec. Why is that?

```
% ruby exec.rb
start
/Users/xxx/code/
```

This is my output when I ran this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Kernel#exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) **replaces** the current running process. Once it's executed, the remaining part of the code is not run.

```
puts "start"
ret1 = exec('pwd')  # <---- After this, no more remaining code is executed.
...
```

If you want to get the output of the command, use [`` Kernel#` ``](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-60) instead:

```
puts "start"
ret1 = `pwd`
```

Comment: the problem is i use string in exec() function.  seems backslick cannot handle that case.

Comment: @BufBills, Do you mean your command is constructed using string variable? You can use string interpolation: \`ls #{path}\`